# How to delete blank cells and reset the UsedRange in C#

Tags: excel

I have spreadsheet has 2 columns and 1000 rows with data. But the spreadsheet has some formatting , with NO data in columns AA to  AZ. I only want my spreadsheet to contain the values in columns 1,2  (A,B) and the rows, So the '**UsedRange**' becomes just columns A and B and the 1000 rows.  I know I can locate Blank cells with `.**SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeBlanks**

1. How do I clear the formatting of the blank ('used cells').  I do a Delete? once the range is selected?
2. Delete clears the formatting, but it appears the used range still includes columns AA to AZ. I want a 'clean' spreadsheet. How do I 'reset' the UsedRange? to A1..B1000?  - Just my data?  Do I save it as new spreadsheet?

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer below is not in C# but hopefully should provide some use.

1. To clear the formatting of the empty cells you can use Range.ClearFormats method.
2. To reset the used range you can try a = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count which should re-set the used range.

Otherwise this page shows a more involved reset procedure:
https://access-excel.tips/excel-vba-usedrange-property/

If that still fails I would delete all empty columns to the right and then delete all rows below your data. Done in bulk it should be quick and would have the benefit of clearing formatting and re-setting the used range in one.

Answer (score 1):

Using VBA, give this a try:

```
Sub Kleanup()
    Range("C1:XFD1").EntireColumn.Delete
    Range("A1001:A1048576").EntireRow.Delete
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
End Sub
```

This will leave **A1:B1000** un-touched.